# Android tableview crashing on titanium Appcelerator SDK 7.5.0

Tags: android, sdk, appcelerator-titanium

I am getting the following error only on Android when I click on table view which has a custom table row. Can someone please help me understand this?

> TiExceptionHandler: (main) [5645,45992] Attempt to invoke virtual met
>       hod 'void org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiUIView.registerForTouch()' on a null 
>       object reference
>       [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:
>       [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.h
>       andleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:594)
>       [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.h
>       andleMessage(TiViewProxy.java:270)
>       [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
>       va:102)
>       [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>       [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
>       d.java:6669)
>       [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method
>       )
>       [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAnd
>       ArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>       [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
>       eInit.java:858)

Answer (score 2):

OK i just removed the console.log(JSON.stringify(e));  in code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

UI View and UITableView are Classes that belongs to Apple iOS SDK, so those objects can never be Instantiated with Android, I am impress that Titanium didn't detect the wrong compatibility.

In android you should use ListView or RecyclerView, the most similar name object that Android contains is TableLayout but is barely used.